Is it normal for a retired show dog to pull on the leash?
I visited a Cairn Terrier breeder who claimed a dog for sale, 1.5 years, was a retired and trained show dog. The dog does not respond to the word sit and pulls on the leash while walking, even on short leash. Apparently the dog had walked for half an hour that day beforehand.
Is this expected behaviour?

Can you perhaps elaborate what your motivation and underlying concern is? A question of “is it normal” can have answers between “yes” and “no”, but I’m not sure whether either is particularly useful for you. Seems you have some general doubts and are fixing it on one issue?

There's a few things to consider - dogs don't behave uniformly to everyone and a show dog would have had a designated trainer who was familiar with it. Terriers are notoriously stubborn and independant and very high energy. Does it listen to the trainer?

Thanks all. Yes of course, @Stephie, the underlying motivation is understanding whether the claims about the background of the dog are true. While it was papered and had been entered in shows (doesn't seem to be a winner as claimed by the breeder, not that it is a concern), the dog generally seemed untrained.  It was also kept outside for most of its life.

@JourneymanGeek It was quite "stubborn, independent, and high energy" in comparison to say, a pure breed Golden Retriever with show parents trained with basic obedience (only point of potential reference.) Generally it seemed like an untrained dog. Please also see previous comment re: being kept outside, which seemed strange for a show dog (perhaps not?)

Kept outside is a little strange, but stubborn, independant and high energy seems... very typically terrier, as a former terrier companion. :D

Thank you everyone! Very helpful.

It's quite common for show dogs not to be taught "sit": the thinking is that if you teach "sit", they learn that it's a normal behavior, and you don't ever want a dog to sit at the wrong moment in the show ring, like when the judge approaches the dog for the examination, or when they're taking the final look at all the dogs in the ring. (Some people teach "stand", since reinforcing a desired behavior can be easier than eliminating an undesired one.)
"Retired" means only that the owner has decided not to show the dog any more; it doesn't really imply anything about success or lack of it in the show ring.
With regards to the pulling, the show environment is going to be very different from what the dog is used to: strange location, lots of strange dogs around, possibly a strange human at the other end of the leash, possibly a different leash (show leashes tend to have a narrow thin collar so as not to interfere with the judge's view of the dog).
Anecdotal evidence for the last: I have a dog that would behave perfectly until the moment I stepped into the show ring, then would start pulling as strongly as he could, arching his back and choking just as the judge was getting their first impression of all the dogs. Another dog was perfect in the show ring on a show leash, but she's a chore to walk on her normal flat collar because she'll pull for the first 15 to 20 minutes before settling down.

Another example: Guide dogs are trained to he very focused on their job when "on duty", meaning when they are wearing their harness. Taking it off them and putting on the collar is a signal that they are "off duty" and allowed to play, nap, and otherwise just be pet dogs for a while. But, yes "show dog" without more detail is aspirational, not a promise. And may imply that the dog is overbred...

Many thanks all, this has helped tremendously!

in response to "Cairn Terrier breeder who claimed a dog for sale, 1.5 years, was a retired and trained show dog."
I am a pro dog walker (for a decade), mostly off lead now. Like some people have alluded to,  Terriers do have strong wills.  They are NOT stubborn, they are doing what they were evolved to do.  They are great hunters, and love to dig and hunt vermin. This means that they were bred to be independent.  That said, once you train a hunting dog, properly, consistently,  regularly.  They can become one of the best 'trained dogs' around.
Unless you put the hours in, and do it regularly, they will figure stuff out for themselves and resist change, because they dont see you as their leader, just the feeder and friend.
Also be very aware that any small breed dog will still often be considered a puppy between 0 and 4 years of age.  With age, can come some level of maturity. But when young puppies love to play and sleep and explore. Your training has to be in small pieces. I would recommend any reputable volunteer training group in your area to achieve this, and do it with them at least weekly. Your own training with your dog should be for short periods, several times per day, with rewards.
I also know that not all show dogs are trained to voice command. Some are just for aesthetic show of code and physical traits, not doing tasks.
Cairn Terriers can be great pets, but do take substantial time, and patience initially to get them to listen consistently.  Good luck on your journey.
